# 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb' '

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using python3 to learn flask. When i connected it to a Mysql database using xampp, it shows the above mentioned error. is it a version problem or something else?

Comment: did you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Run  the command below to add the python mysql  connector to your python environment.

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of the following commands. Which one depends on what OS and software you have and use.

easy_install mysql-python (mix os)

pip install mysql-python (mix os/ python 2)

pip install mysqlclient (mix os/ python 3)

apt-get install python-mysqldb (Linux Ubuntu, ...)

cd /usr/ports/databases/py-MySQLdb && make install clean (FreeBSD)

yum install MySQL-python (Linux Fedora, CentOS ...)

For Windows, see this answer: Install mysql-python (Windows)